# Make a user of template class independent of the template type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to C++. Just learning.. Say, I have two classes - FrameCapture and ObjectTracker.
ObjectTracker uses FrameCapture as an instance variable.

Here are the classes:

```
template<typename T>
class FrameCapture {
public:
    FrameCapture(T *configOption) : configOption(configOption) {}

    virtual bool nextFrame() const = 0;
private:
    T *configOption;
};
```

and

```
template<typename T>
class ObjectTracker {
public:
    ObjectTracker(FrameCapture<T> *capture) : capture(capture) {}

    virtual void track() const = 0;

private:
    FrameCapture<T> *capture;
};
```

The `FrameCapture` has one config option which is templated. The thing is that I want the `ObjectTracker` to NOT know the template details of the `FrameCapture`. I want to give different instances of the `FrameCapture` to a an instance of the `ObjectTracker` not bothering the `ObjectTracker`'s instance with `FrameCapture`'s implementation details. How can I achieve this?

Heavy critics accepted!

Thank you.

Comment: The types are determined at compilation-time and each struct/class definition must declare its attributes types. A templated class is just a way to generate similar classes but working with different types, each of these generated classes must also fix their attributes' types. You can't have a single class with several instances each of those with attributes of different (possibly) types: you either have to make two different classes (e.g., add a template parameter add pass it down) or abstract the attribute interface using `virtual` (hence deciding at runtime which implementation you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're already using inheritance, you could do:

```
class FrameCaptureBase {
public:
    virtual ~FrameCaptureBase() { }
    virtual bool nextFrame() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class FrameCapture : public FrameCaptureBase {
public:
    FrameCapture(T *configOption) : configOption(configOption) {}

private:
    T *configOption;
};

class ObjectTracker {
public:
    ObjectTracker(FrameCaptureBase *capture) : capture(capture) {}

    virtual void track() const = 0;

private:
    FrameCaptureBase *capture;
};
```

Comment: :) how could I not think of this.. Too much work lately. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're looking for is **type erasure**.

Start by defining the interface of `FrameCapture` in an abstract base class that is not templated.

```
class FrameCapture
{
public:

  virtual ~FrameCapture() noexcept = default;
  virtual bool nextFrame() const = 0;
};
```

The templated versions then *derive* from that interface.

```
template <typename T>
class FrameCaptureImpl : public FrameCapture
{
public:

  FrameCaptureImpl(T *);
  virtual bool nextFrame() const override = 0;

private:

  T * config_;  // Are you sure you want to use a raw pointer here?
};
```

The `ObjectTracker` only uses the non-templated interface.

```
class ObjectTracker
{
public:

  ObjectTracker(FrameCapture *);
  void track() const;

private:

  FrameCapture * capture_;  // Again, are you sure?
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the constructor and configOption from FrameCapture. Derive ConfigurableFrameCapture class from FrameCapture and add it all back. ConfigurableFrameCapture would be a template, FrameCapture is not.